# Why does VirusTotal not detect a McAfee Internet Security Suite virus?

Tags: malware

On my local system, I have McAfee's Internet Security Suite installed. It detected some file on my system as a Trojan. I sent this same file to [VirusTotal](http://virustotal.com), but all the scanners didn't detect anything, even though they have both `McAfee` and `McAfee-GW-Edition` listed as scanners. Why would it detect it on my system and not on VirusTotal?

Answer (score 1):

From the [FAQ](https://www.virustotal.com/faq/#statistics):

> VirusTotal's antivirus engines are commandline versions, so depending
>   on the product, they will not behave exactly the same as the desktop
>   versions: for instance, desktop solutions may use techniques based on
>   behavioural analysis and count with personal firewalls that may
>   decrease entry points and mitigate propagation, etc.
>
> **In VirusTotal desktop-oriented solutions coexist with
>   perimeter-oriented solutions; heuristics in this latter group may be
>   more aggressive and paranoid, since the impact of false positives is
>   less visible in the perimeter. It is simply not fair to compare both
>   groups.**
>
> Some of the solutions included in VirusTotal are parametrized (in
>   coherence with the developer company's desire) with a different
>   heuristic/agressiveness level than the official end-user default
>   configuration.

(Emphasis mine)